# regex to remove digits, allow only lowercase letters, remove special characters

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

Here is my code :

```
private void txtMot_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    /* Clear message */
    txtMessage.Clear();


    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
    Match match = regex.Match(txtMot.Text);

    if (match.Success)
    {
        /* Text in red*/
        txtMessage.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
        /* Message text*/
        txtMessage.Text = "Only letters";
    }
}
```

I managed to remove all the digits.
I'm wondering now, how can I make it to :

- Remove the digits.
- Allow only lowercase letters.
- Remove any kind of special characters(_+ù$é)

How can I do it please?

Comment: Uh, Uhm, `[a-z]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use the regex `[a-z]` and test with different set of data, as it accepts only the `lowercase letters`

```
public static void Main()
{
    string test = "_+ù$é";   //change this to any set of test data
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"[a-z]");
    Match match = regex.Match(test);

    if (match.Success)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Matched");
    }
    else
      Console.WriteLine("Not Matched");

}
```

[dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MgN2fJ)

EDIT:

The above snippet would fail in a scenario where;

```
string test = "_+ù$é abc";
```

^ as this contains both the special letters and the lowercase, if you only want the lowercase letters to be accepted then;

replace this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[a-z]");
```

with this pattern:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([a-z]{1,25})$"); //this makes sure the string 
                                            // is only of lowercase 
                                           // letters and does not contain any digits
                                          // or special chars
```

[dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XfmfMm)

Comment: Oh indeed thank you, it works !
I had a blank and forgot how to do it.

Thanks